# The subroutine ignpoi in the package ranlib.f is broken

Tags: random, fortran, gfortran, numerical-methods

I am using gfortran: GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4 on linux.

I am trying to use `ignpoi` from `ranlib.f` in this source http://www.netlib.org/random/ (http://www.netlib.org/random/ranlib.f.tar.gz)

I compile the library using

```
   gfortran -O2 -c *.f
   ar cr libranlib.a *.o
```

When I write simple program to test ignpoi (Poisson deviate generator)

```
  program test
  implicit none
  integer seed1, seed2, i
  real av
  integer ignpoi

  seed1=123456
  seed2=654321
  call setall(seed1,seed2)

  av=8.0
  do i=1,10
     print *, ignpoi(av)
  enddo

  end
```

with the same average it gives segmentation fault after one or many deviates.

```
          12
           7

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F077F1D3E48
#1  0x7F077F1D2FD0
#2  0x7F077E9042EF
#3  0x401288 in ignpoi_
#4  0x400A3D in MAIN__ at test.f:?
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is how I compile the test with no compilation error.

```
gfortran test.f libranlib.a
```

Oddly enough, when I ask for different number every time, there is no problem. When I comment lines 104-105

```
IF (mu.EQ.muprev) GO TO 10     
IF (mu.LT.10.0) GO TO 120
```

of `ignpoi.f`, the problem is gone.

Can this be replicated?

What cause the errors?

I get that line 104-105 are to save calculation time. How can I modify the current function to benefit from the pre-calculation without that problem of calling the function with the same average multiple time?

Comment: Enable debugging symbols and simple checks by `gfortran -g -fbacktrace -Wall -check=all` and report your findings. It is likely that you will need to show the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that particular code is broken... In `ignpoi.f`, ll. 218:

```
      IF (mu.EQ.muold) GO TO 130
      muold = mu
      m = max0(1,ifix(mu))
      l = 0
      p = exp(-mu)
      q = p
      p0 = p
C
C     STEP U. UNIFORM SAMPLE FOR INVERSION METHOD
C
  130 u = ranf()
```

The first condition is true, so you skip the initialization of `m`, `l`, `p`, `q`, and `p0`. Of these variables, only `l` is touched before - but this is also skipped for `mu == muold`.

Unfortunately, quite a lot of the subsequent calculations/branches depend on the mentioned variables, which leads to - excuse the pun - random behavior.

I do not know where the segfault occured in your case, on my machine I end up with an endless loop. The simplest solution would be to disable storing the old value. For this, comment out (or delete) the lines (144 & 219)

```
      muold = mu
```

Or, disable jumping over the initialization (l. 218):

```
C     IF (mu.EQ.muold) GO TO 130
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any other known issues of that sort in ranlib.f? Also, what are the alternative "packages" for random number generator in Fortran (compatible with gfortran)? I need Poisson, real uniform, integer uniform, binomial, and Gaussian.

Comment: @wallace1837 Sorry, I do not have any experience with ranlib.f my answer stems purely from analyzing `ignpoi.f`. For all my projects that involved stochastics (very few) `random_number()` was sufficient.